# Error while using recycler view in fragments

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use the recycler view in fragments.
But the app is crashing and showing this error.
The error shown is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mridul.expressions, PID: 7690
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.mridul.expressions.DiaryViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.mridul.expressions.DiaryFragment.onViewCreated(DiaryFragment.kt:31)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.mridul.expressions.DiaryFragment.onViewCreated(DiaryFragment.kt:31) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.mridul.expressions.DiaryDatabase. DiaryDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:97)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:1358)
        at com.mridul.expressions.DiaryDatabase$Companion.getDatabase(DiaryDatabase.kt:25)
        at com.mridul.expressions.DiaryViewModel.<init>(DiaryViewModel.kt:14)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.mridul.expressions.DiaryFragment.onViewCreated(DiaryFragment.kt:31) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

My Fragment.kt file:

```
        package com.mridul.expressions

    import android.app.Application
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_diary.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_diary.view.*
    import java.util.Calendar.getInstance


class DiaryFragment : Fragment(), IDiaryRVAdapter {

    lateinit var viewModel: DiaryViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val adapter= this.context?.let { DiaryRVAdapter(it,this) }
        diaryRecyclerView.adapter=adapter
        diaryRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(
        this.context)

        val application: Application =requireActivity().application
        viewModel=ViewModelProvider(this,
                ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)).get(DiaryViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.allDiary.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {list->
            list?.let {
                adapter?.updateList(it)
            }
        })
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diary, container, false)

        view.saveDiaryButton.setOnClickListener {
            val diaryText=dateInDiary.text.toString()
            if (diaryText.isNotEmpty()){
                viewModel.insertNode(Diary(diaryText))
            }
            dateInDiary.text = null
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(diary: Diary) {
        viewModel.deleteNode(diary)
    }


}
```

My Adapter is:

```
     class DiaryRVAdapter(private val context: Context,
    private val listner:IDiaryRVAdapter) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DiaryRVAdapter.DiaryViewHolder>() 
    {
    val allNotes=ArrayList<Diary>()

    inner class DiaryViewHolder(itemView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val textView=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item)
        val deletButton=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.deleteButton)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DiaryViewHolder {
        
       valviewHolder=DiaryViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate
       (R.layout.item_diary,parent,false))
        viewHolder.deletButton.setOnClickListener{
            listner.onItemClicked(allNotes[viewHolder.adapterPosition])}
        return viewHolder
    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DiaryViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentNotes=allNotes[position]
        holder.textView.text = currentNotes.text
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return allNotes.size

    }
    fun updateList(newList: List<Diary>){
        allNotes.clear()
        allNotes.addAll(newList)

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

interface IDiaryRVAdapter{
    fun onItemClicked(diary: Diary)
}
```

And layout file of fragment is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dearDiaryTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:text="@string/dear_diary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#d500f9"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dateInDiary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dearDiaryTxt"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:hint="Date-\nHow was your day"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_round_box"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveDiaryButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dateInDiary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:text="Save"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/diaryRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/saveDiaryButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_diary"
    />
```

And item is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteButton"
    tools:text="Mridul"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textColor="#3e2723"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/item"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/item"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_outline_24"
    />
```

Please Help anyone.

Comment: Can you make sure you import the synthetic property for your recycler view from the correct fragment xml (I see import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_write.* in your imports - probably it is taken from there).

Comment: Thanks that was a mistake too. 
But even after change the problem persist.
Can you suggest something else too Please

Comment: Now I guess the problem is with my view model.

Comment: The problem actually now is with Room. Check the stacktrace: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.mridul.expressions.DiaryDatabase. DiaryDatabase_Impl does not exist.

Comment: Sorry but I still can't point my mistake can you please elaborate about what you mentioned